# Checking for a prime number through user input in a given range in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int n=0;
  int x;
  printf("Please enter a number:");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  (x<=1)&&(x>=1000)&&(x=(!(n)));
  if((n/1)&&(n/n)&&(!(n/x)))
  {
    printf("P\n");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("C\n");
  }
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

My code keeps outputting "P" from the if statement when run, can anyone explain why? Is there a way to make the code work with just if and else functions? If so please help

Comment: x is undefined, im assuming you wanted scanf("%d", &x) not &n

Comment: what is the purpose of `(x<=1)&&(x>=1000)&&(x=(!(n)));` ?

Comment: how can x be both less than 1 and greater than 1000?

Comment: You are not assigning the value to x, it will be garbage, we cannot predict the value of x and output

Comment: i was trying to write a range for x between 1 and a 1000, but excluding the number the user has input

Comment: there is quite a few issues with this code. I would recommend starting with looking at how to format a for loop, then looking at the modulo operator. If you are familiar with prime numbers this should give you a good foundation of how you can solve this problem

Comment: Search like `isPrime` in this site.

Comment: Thanks, i will look into these

Answer (score 0):

I believe the intent of this `if((n/1)&&(n/n)&&(!(n/x)))` statement is saying "if n is divisible by one and if n is divisible by n and if n is not divisible by x" however this is not how we express these ideas in C. Look at the % or modulo operator and see if you can figure out how we can express these ideas using logic